# Uploading files with variable data to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, fs, cloud-storage

I would like to upload a textfile which contains some variables that is received by my server previously.
For example when user 1 sends some data, I want to create and upload a file by the name **USER1.txt** and it contains details for **USER1**. Similarly when USER2 sends his data, a new file **USER2.txt** with the details of **USER2** is created and uploaded to Google Cloud Storage.

This is what I have tried

```js
   const filename = "./details.txt";
   const content = 'this contains some random variables declared previously';
   fs.writeFileSync(filename,content);
   await savetocloud('my-bucket',filename);
});

const savetocloud = async function(bucketName, filename) {
   async function uploadFile() {
      await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename,{
         gzip:true,
         metadata:{
            cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
         }
      });
      console.log('${filename} uplaoded to ${bucketname}');
   }
   uploadFile().catch(console.error);
```

This program works perfectly and the file is also uploaded when it is executed in localhost. However, when I deploy this app to app engine, it doesn't work.

**Edit:** This is my app.yaml file.

```
runtime: nodejs12
automatic_scaling:
target_cpu_utilization: 0.85

handlers:
- url: /javascript
static_dir: javascript
- url: /style
static_dir: style
- url: /coverphoto
static_dir: coverphoto
- url: /slidephoto
static_dir: slidephoto
```

Comment: How are you trying to deploy this code in App Engine? Could you please also share us the yaml file and the error message that you are getting?

Comment: It is not showing any errors or anything, it just does not upload the file to cloud storage. I have added my app.yaml file as asked.

Comment: Taking into account that you are deploying an App Engine application, I understand that you have been able to deploy the app but now the upload object to GCS functionallity is not working. Where do you have the file you want to upload to GCS?